# setState interferes with control of setTimeout

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

This React application runs a counter that increments a count variable every two seconds, and updates the display to the browser.  The user can start and stop the counter with buttons for each, respectively.  It works exactly as expected without the `setCount` function, but when this function is enabled, the counter cannot be stopped by either a flag to halt the timer (*killswitch*) or the `clearInterval`.  The user needs to be able to see the count, so updating state is obviously necessary, and can't be omitted.

**Why does the timer control become disconnected from the program?**  My semi-educated noob guess is that it is disconnecting something during the rendering of state.

**Is there a way to fix this?**

```
import { useState } from 'react'

export default function Counter() {

    let timer = null
    let killswitch = false

    const [currentCount, setCount] = useState(0)

    const start = () => {
        if ( killswitch ) return
        setCount( prev => prev + 1 )
        timer = setTimeout(start, 2000)
    }

    const stop = () => {
        clearTimeout(timer)
        killswitch = true
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <p>{currentCount}</p>
            <p>
                <button onClick={start}>Start</button>
                <button onClick={stop}>Stop</button>
            </p>
        </div>
    )

} // Counter()
```

Using `setInterval` is not an option for this program, because it is correcting drift between iterations which can't be done in the interval loop.

This program was also tried with useState for both the **killswitch** and timer **variables**.  That had no impact on the issue, so I chose the standard javascript variable form for this example, to reduce clutter in the code.

Comment: There is a typo. `onclick` would be `onClick`. Try using the state variable version and update if there is still an issue

Comment: @TusharShahi That typo is only here.  I hand typed the code for the question.  It's not in the actual program, where it would have caused a failure.  It's not related to the issue in the question.

Comment: Check this : https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-ptolemy-ub7dln?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Well you need to save `timer` and `killswitch ` into state since otherwise the `let timer` and `let killswitch ` will be reset each time the component rerenders.

Comment: `if ( killswitch ) return` so once stopped, you will not be able to start it again. Seems poorly designed. (in addition to the fact that you can't use plain variables to track state in a component, as already mentioned)

Comment: @super - you can use plain variables for this.  See Nicholas Tower's answer which fixes the problem.  The question was how to stop the timer, not to start or restart the timer.  I never said anything about a need to restart it, or that I want the user to be able to do so.

Comment: @TusharShahi That works, perfectly.  Does the local scoping of the timer eliminate the problem of timeout references being deleted with the rendering, as Ubaldo Suarez mentioned in his answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time your component renders, you create a brand new `timer` variable. This is a local variable that's only visible to the specific render in which is was created. If you started the timer on a previous render, you can only cancel it on that same render, not on a later one.

Instead, you need a variable that persists from one render to the next. The two options for this are state or a ref, and since the value needed for rendering i'd recommend a ref:

```
export default function Counter() {

    const timer = useRef(null);
    const killswitch = useRef(false);

    const [currentCount, setCount] = useState(0)

    const start = () => {
        if ( killswitch.current ) return
        setCount( prev => prev + 1 )
        timer.current = setTimeout(start, 2000)
    }

    const stop = () => {
        clearTimeout(timer.current)
        killswitch.current = true
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <p>{currentCount}</p>
            <p>
                <button onClick={start}>Start</button>
                <button onClick={stop}>Stop</button>
            </p>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: There is still the logical error here that `start` will not do anything after calling `stop`, so there's no way to start the timer again. Probably better to get rid of `killswitch` completely. The timer being `null` is enough to know that it's currently not running.

Comment: @super is it still a logical error if the intention is not to have the user able to restart the timer?  The question was about stopping the timer, not restarting it.

Answer (score 1):

When you perform a setState action the component is re-rendered, at this moment a new timeout is executed but the old timeout is running yet in memory and this is the problem with your component you can stop the recently rendered timeout but old timeout references are deleted.

But don't worry the best way to handle timmers in react is performing a cleanup in a useEffect hook

const [start, setStart] = useState(false)

```
useEffect(() => {
let interval;
if(start) {
  interval = setInterval(() => getTime(deadline), 1000);
  setStart(false)
}
//perform a cleanup
return () => clearInterval(interval);  }, [start]);
```

The effect should be executed only when the start state changes and the return in the effect is the cleanup function that clear the interval when the component is unmounted, fixed the timmer you must look for other ways to implement the killSwitch

Learn how to handle timmers clearly [explained here](https://dev.to/emmaadesile/build-a-timer-using-react-hooks-3he2)

Comment: Nicholas Tower's answer fixed the problem, but upvote for explaining that old timeout references are deleted.  That's helpful information!